# How do I pause Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I recently purchased Minecraft Pocket Edition for Android and I started to play and after I finished I couldn't find the pause button where is it?

Answer (score 5):

Going into the menu will pause the game. From the [Minecraft wiki Android controls section](http://minecraft.wikia.com/wiki/Minecraft:_Pocket_Edition):

> - Circle: Cycle inventory right
> - Square: Cycle inventory left
> - Triangle: Bring up inventory
> - D-Pad: Move
> - Right Touchpad: Look/Turn
> - **Menu: Pause**

Where the red circle is:

[image: Screenshot of Minecraft with a red circle in the upper right]

Comment: But there's normally a menu button some where right?

Comment: @Eli Top right: http://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/minecraft.gamepedia.com/thumb/d/dc/Pocket_Edition.jpg/300px-Pocket_Edition.jpg

Comment: Why do my answers keep getting downvoted?  They are all correct, and they link to official sources...

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't have that little pause button

Comment: @Eli It may look like 3 little dots instead.

Comment: Nope I don't even have that. Hmmm?

Comment: @Eli What device are you playing on?

Comment: On my kindle fire i bring up the bar on the bottom(or side pending on version)and press back or the menu button and it brings up the menu but does not stop mobs or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Tap the menu button on your device.