# Mindcraft pocket addition on ipad

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My daughtersister Minecraft characters are no longer forward facing.
She can only see their backs.  I don't know how to fix this for her.

Also, the controls are no longer visible on her screen, so she can't maneuver her player properly or save etc.

Comment: your... your daughtersister? Is her name Antigone?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're talking about this?

**[How do you change between views?](http://minemum.com/change-view)**

```
It's super easy to toggle between the three views:

PC - press F5
Mac - press Function + F5
---> Pocket Edition - pause the game and swap between views in the Options menu
Xbox 360 & PS3 - left game stick
```

It sounds like your daughtersister set the view to "3rd Person" to see more of the world, but you would only be able to see her character's back as well.  The PAUSE button should be here:

[image]

Image from: [How do I pause Minecraft Pocket Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/152817/how-do-i-pause-minecraft-pocket-edition)